# AWK: Compare two files and calculate a percentage based on differences

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files as these..
What I need is to count the number of times each ID appears on each file and calculate the difference to obtain percentage of success. Furthermore, when the third column of the first file contains the word NONE and the same column of the second file contains a number, indicate that has been obtained category for that ID.

File 1:

```
ID;Coments;Category
2;es un anuncio interesante que le puede servir para alguien;321
3;es un anuncio de un banco que quiere presentarse como una compañía;NONE
4;es un anuncio de un banco que ofrece prestamos para empresas.;70
5;credito pyme bana para hacer crecer tu negocio;50
5;credito pyme bana para hacer crecer tu negocio;52
5;credito pyme bana para hacer crecer tu negocio;70
5;credito pyme bana para hacer crecer tu negocio;71
6;comercial que te hace pensar en considerar a bana para poner tu  negocio;50
6;comercial que te hace pensar en considerar a bana para poner tu negocio;71
7;este anuncio da una breve explicación sobre el tratamiento de hemodialisis;50
8;un anucio de bana donde muestra que se puede pedir un crédito para emprender;50
8;un anucio de bana donde muestra que se puede pedir un crédito para emprender;52
8;un anucio de bana donde muestra que se puede pedir un crédito para emprender;70
8;un anucio de bana donde muestra que se puede pedir un crédito para emprender;71
9;bonito;NONE
```

File 2:

```
ID;Coments;Category
2;es un anuncio interesante que le puede servir para alguien;321
3;es un anuncio de un banco que quiere presentarse como una compañía;57
4;es un anuncio de un banco que ofrece prestamos para empresas.;50
5;credito pyme bana para hacer crecer tu negocio;52
6;comercial que te hace pensar en considerar a bana para poner tu negocio;50
7;este anuncio da una breve explicación sobre el tratamiento de hemodialisis;210
8;un anucio de bana donde muestra que se puede pedir un crédito para emprender;50
9;bonito;303
```

Desired Output:

```
For the ID-2, we have achieved a 100% success rate.
For the ID-3, we have achieved a category.
For the ID-4, we have achieved a 100% success rate.
For the ID-5, we achieved a 25% success rate.
For the ID-5, we achieved a 50% success rate.
For the ID-7, we have achieved a 100% success rate.
For the ID-8, we have achieved a 25% success rate.
For the ID-9, we have achieved a category.
```

One approach could be this small. But of course, I need to calculate percentages and print it on like my desired output format.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" } NR==FNR{cnt[$1]++; next} { cnt2[$1]++;}  END{ for (ID in cnt){ print ID, "CAT: "cnt[ID],"Manual: "cnt2[ID];}}'
```

Comment: So what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: If an event is labelled `NONE` in the 1st file, you're interested ONLY in it having achieved a category? you're not interested in its success rate?  --- ---- Further, is it possible that in the 2nd file there is an ID not mentioned in the 1st one? and, if this is the case, do we want to report the issue? in which terms?

Comment: To give you an idea, it's like each file were the results of a team, if the first team has hit four times with ID-5 and the second team only one. We show the results, saying that we have a 20% success rate with respect to ID-5. If the first team has the word NONE in the third column and the second team has a number, then we show the results, saying that "we have achived a category". Can you help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk is for this

```
awk -F ';' '
   FNR==1{next}
   FNR==NR{C1[$1]++;N1[$1]=($3!~/NONE/);next}
   {C2[$1]++;if($3!~/NONE/)N2[$1]++}
   END{
      for(c in C1){
         if((N1[c]==0)&&(C2[c]>0)&&(N2[c]>0)){
            S="we have achieved a category."
            }
          else S=sprintf( "we have achieved a %d%% success rate.", C2[c]*100/C1[c])
         printf "For the ID-%d, %s\n", c, S
         }
      }' file1 file2
```